# How to apply Core Image filters one at a time to save memory consumption?

Tags: ios, ios5, core-image

When you apply a number of Core Image filters to an image, memory can quickly become a limiting factor (and often leading to a crash of the application). I was therefore wondering what a good approach is to add one filter at a time and wait for each operation to complete.

The example that I am working on involves one photo to which the user can apply various effects/filters. The user is presented with a small thumbnail to get an idea of what each filter looks like. When all the filters are applied at one, the application runs out of its assigned amount of memory and crashes.

In short, how do I go about applying one filter at a time and be notified when the operation is complete so I can apply the next filter to the next thumbnail?

Comment: Is the crash occurring on the thumbnail preview or the processing of the final image? It sounds like the former, so can you scale the image down and use the smaller thumbnail source image for input to your Core Image filters?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Brad. I ended up doing that, but when I load a bunch of thumbnails it ends up taking quite a bit before they are loaded. Showing a activity indicator for each thumbnail is a good start to tell the user that something is in progress, but the UI is unresponsive as long as CI is doing its job.

Comment: Is the bottleneck in the Core Graphics resizing operation or Core Image processing? If Core Image, may I suggest a possible alternative: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage ? For still images, I see a 4X improvement in filtering performance over Core Image on an iPhone 4. If I'm missing a filter you need, let me know and I might be able to quickly add it.

Comment: This is very impressive, Brad, the benchmarks compared to CI in particular. I have two questions about this. (1) Is including the GPUImage project the best way to include GPUImage? (2) Why is there an upper limit in terms of image size (currently at 2048px)? Thanks very much.

Comment: Embedding the project per the instructions I have on GitHub is probably the cleanest way to bring this in. We tried a number of different approaches with Core Plot, and this always seemed to be the simplest for iOS libraries. The 2048 pixel upper limit is for older devices (not the iPad 2, iPad 3, and iPhone 4S, which can handle 4096x4096 ones) because that is the maximum texture size for the GPUs in those devices. I need to implement a tiling mechanism to manage images larger than this.

Comment: I have one final question regarding GPUImage. Based on the information on the GitHub page, does this mean that GPUImage is not able to process an image taken with an iPhone 4? The latter has a 5MP camera, which means that it does exceed the 2048px boundary imposed on devices prior to the iPhone 4S. I suppose dividing the image into several tiles and applying each filter to each tile is a possible workaround for this limitation.

Comment: No, it currently can't process the full resolution of a still photo taken with an iPhone 4 (this is part of the reason why I don't yet have a still camera input as a direct source). Even Core Image drops down to CPU-bound processing for images larger than 2048, although I want to go with tiles that get stitched together for this. I suppose I could slightly downsample from 2592 x 1936 to 2048 x 1530, but I'd prefer to have a solution for the native resolution of the images.