# Applying core image filters - app crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, core-image

I use the following code for applying a few types of image filters. (there are three more 'editImage' functions for brightness, saturation and contrast, with a common completeImageUsingOutput method). I use a slider to vary their values.
If I work with any of them individually, it works fine. As soon as I make two function calls on two different filters, the app crashed.

**EDIT:** didReceiveMemoryWarning is called. I see the memory allocations using memory leaks instrument, and after each edit memory allocation increases by around 15mb

The crash happens during
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent];

Moreover, if the instructions completeImageUsingOutputImage method are put into the individual functions, I am able to work with two types of filters without crashing. As soon as I call the third one, the app crashes.

(filters and context have been declared as instance variables and initialized in the init method)

```
- (UIImage *)editImage:(UIImage *)imageToBeEdited tintValue:(float)tint
{
CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:imageToBeEdited];
NSLog(@"in edit Image:\ncheck image: %@\ncheck value:%f", image, tint);

[tintFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[tintFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tint] forKey:@"inputAngle"];

CIImage *outputImage = [tintFilter outputImage];
NSLog(@"check output image: %@", outputImage);
return [self completeEditingUsingOutputImage:outputImage];
}

- (UIImage *)completeEditingUsingOutputImage:(CIImage *)outputImage
{
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent];
NSLog(@"check cgimg: %@", cgimg);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
NSLog(@"check newImge: %@", newImage);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return newImage;
}
```

**EDIT :** using these filters on a reduced sized image is working now, but still, it would be good if I why was some memory not being released before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748220/how-to-apply-core-image-filters-one-at-a-time-to-save-memory-consumption?rq=1

Now this becomes my question. Still Unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in at top most of completeEditingUsingOutputImage: method

```
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
```

Also this is how get CIImage:

```
    CIImage *outputImage = [tintFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

Comment: I tried both the things, but it didn't work. (See that I have added an EDIT to my question)